# WSO2 API Manager - Can I hide tenant stores in the public store?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to hide tenant stores, so the they aren't visible in the public store, but only by their direct tenant specific store URL (like: https://api.mydomain.com/store/?tenant=mycustomer.com)?

**Background info:**
All our customers get their own tenant in the WSO2 API Manager. When an anonymous/unauthenticated visitor opens the public store (https://api.mydomain.com/store) he/she will see all tenant stores and their domain names. So it isn't really hard to discover the names of all our customers. This is undesirable. I know that the public store is supposed to promote public API's, but we don't offer public API's (yet).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. First you have to configure api manager to Single Sign-on with SAML2 Please refer this for more details about [Single Sign-on with SAML2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2)

Now you have to do some modification on getting login popup when we access the store, as explained below. We can use the subthemes to achieve this customization. Please follow the below instructions to try out the login popup for the store, but this will take you to the tenant listing page once you logged in.

1) In the case you already have a sub theme, then you can use that else you can create the sub themes under the directory AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/fancy/subthemes directory.

2) And the copy the template.jag from AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/fancy/templates/menu/primary/template.jag to AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/fancy/subthemes//templates/menu/primary/template.jag (Please note during this you may need to create the sub directories as mentioned in the destination path). And then please copy the below code

3) Copy the code block given in below to the top of the template.jag page which we created in the step-2.

```html
<%
include("/jagg/jagg.jag");
var user = jagg.getUser();
var mod,httpUrl,httpsUrl;
mod = jagg.module("manager");
httpsUrl= mod.getHTTPsURL();
var httpsURL = httpsUrl + request.getRequestURI();

if(request.getQueryString())
{ httpsURL += "?" + request.getQueryString(); }

if(!user)
{ session.put("showLogin","true"); }

%>
```

4) Go to AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json file, and then add the subtheme as shown in below.

```css
"theme" :
{ "base" : "fancy", "subtheme" : "<name_of_the_theme>" }
```

Now start the server and to https://localhost:9443/store then you will be promt with login popup.