# WSO2 API Manager: Hiding API to specific customers?

Tags: api, wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager

I am creating a library of APIs (let say API A, B and C), and I want to deploy differently for different customers.

Let's say, the customer 1 is able to browse, subscribe and use A and B, and the customer 2 is able to use B and C. But, the most important, I don't want that customer 1 knows about API C, and also, the customer 2 has to ignore API A.

I'm trying 2 methods:

a) Multitenant configuration: This has several issues (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769717/wso2-api-manager-can-i-hide-tenant-stores-in-the-public-store)), but, even I'm not able to hide the API C (when the customer/tenant 1 goes to subscribe to main store, it sees all APIs)

b) Roles and Scopes restriction (I'm following this [post](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/01/article-an-overview-of-scope-management-with-wso2-api-manager/)). This has some advantages (fine grained access per resource/operation), but, again, doesn't hide the APIs in store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control API permissions in publisher, you can use [Access Control Support for API Publisher](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Access+Control+Support+for+API+Publisher) feature.

To control visibility in store, you can use [Store Visibility and Subscription Availability](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Key+Concepts#KeyConcepts-APIvisibilityandsubscriptionAvailability) feature.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to change visibility (in Publisher or Store) after API creation?

Comment: Thanks again! I'll double check. I don't have access now, but when I tried in the past, I have to recreate the API to change the visibility (first tab in publisher). Or maybe my memory is wrong.

Comment: I have double checked. It seems that only admin (or some specific role that I don't know) can change visibility for past created APIs. Normal developers (with creator profile) or lifecycle responsible (with publisher profile) cannot.